# Calculating KDE from weighted data using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, arguments, kernel-density

I want to calculate (not just plot) a KDE of weighted data using SciPy.
However, despite what I found at [the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), I cannot seem to pass all three arguments to the function.

E.g. this bit of code:

```
from scipy import stats

values = np.random.lognormal(size=1000)
weights = np.random.choice([1.0,10.0,100.0], size=len(values))

kde_pdf = stats.gaussian_kde(np.log10(values), 'scott', weights)
```

results in the error `TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`

I have tried other permutations of keyworded and non-keyworded arguments, but nothing seems to work. How can I get the KDE pdf from my weighted data?

Comment: Works for me. Can you check which version of scipy you are using (with `pip freeze | grep scipy` or in your python console `scipy.__version__`)?

Comment: The handling of weights was added to `gaussian_kde` in scipy 1.2.0.

Comment: Thank (both of) you! That was the issue! I thought I had updated my SciPy to the newest version after this did not work, but `scipy.__version__` returned 1.1.0 . After some pain, I managed to install 1.2.1, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The code works in scipy version 1.2.0 and above. I made sure to upgrade to 1.2.1 and found no more problems.